# How do you edit the "Style" section of a table view prototype cell?

Tags: swift

For the Swift table view prototype Cell, it allows you to set the style = "Right Detail", which allows two text fields, one on the left and one on the right.

The left text field can be accessed through the following code.

```
cell.textLabel?.text
```

But does anyone know how to access the right text field (aka "Detail"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Your text"
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help on this simple thing. Even after looking up 30 minutes online I couldn't find this syntax.